# Want to setup web server with IP that is not on my local network

Tags: networking

I am on the local network 192.168.180.1.
However I want to setup a web server (Windows/Linux) with IP 169.254.1.0 on my local network

I can set a static IP for the server to 169.254.1.0, but I don't think it is possible to route to it from a device that is on 192.168.180.1. So setting the default gateway to 192.168.180.1 for 169.254.1.0 does not make sense.

Is there anything I can do or is this impossible to do?
Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: is 169.254.1.0 your routers public IP address?

Comment: No. Just a static IP I need to run a test

Comment: Serms an odd public IP... 169.254. is fairly recognised as being an APIPA address... a .0 address is also the network IP so why would you want to use this? Why not have the machine use an IP on your existing subnet?

Comment: Why do you need a static IP in the link local space? And you can add multiple IPs on devices usually so the other device can also have an address on the same block.

Comment: You need to set a static route on the server, and on the gateway for the 192.168.180.1 network

Comment: Maybe there is a way to setup an alias on the server such that 169.254.1.0 actually goes to an IP in the local network.?? What I need is to be able to use the IP 169.254.1.0 or 169.254.1.1. It is hard coded somewhere which I don't have permission to change.

Comment: @cde: Note that `192.168.180.1` _is not a network_. It's a specific host on that network (I'm guessing it's the router's IP). The _network_ would probably be `192.168.180.0` (or `192.168.180.0/24` since the subnet mask is a necessary part of it).

Comment: @grawity pedantic, but yes. As .1 is the gateway, the routing table for that network will be on there.

Answer (score 3):

169.254.x.x/16 is what the IETF calls the IPv4 Link-Local subnet ("APIPA" is Microsoft's proprietary jargon for this). If your devices' IP stacks follow IETF ZeroConf recommendations, then they should treat that subnet as a local subnet even if they don't have an IP address on that subnet. So what you're considering should just work, no special setup needed.

Contrary to some comments here, 169.254.1.0 is NOT the network address for this subnet, because this is a /16 (netmask 255.255.0.0) subnet, not a /24 (255.255.255.0).

Ideally, if you need a static IP on this subnet, it should have zero or 255 in the third octet (169.254.0.x or 169.254.255.x), because 169.254.1.0 through 168.254.254.255 are reserved for automatic self-assignment, not manual assignment.

See [RFC 3927](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3927.txt) for more information.

Comment: Would it be possible that `169.254.1.0` is indeed the network address? After all, OP hasn't specified netmask, and is free to choose a /24. Even if RFC 3927 / 5735 define it as a /16, that doesn't prevent users from subnetting it further for their own purposes. In fact, the RFC is explicit about this: "This specification is intended for use with small ad hoc networks ... Although 65024 IPv4 Link-Local addresses are available in principle...Network operators with more than 1300 hosts on a single link may want to consider dividing that single link into two or more subnets."

Comment: @ssnobody The thing is, IP stacks that know about RFC 3927 will automatically create a route for 169.254/16 as directly attached to a local interface. I suppose you could find a way to disable or override the automatic behavior so you can set whatever subnet mask you want, but I don't think anyone really does that. Plus, OP mentioned in a comment that he has software that he can't change that hard-coded 169.254.1.0 as a web server address, so apparently the software he's dealing with doesn't think it's a network address either.

Comment: Adding an IP on the `169.254.1.0` net to other hosts with the subnet set to `255.255.255.0` will create a route entry for the /24 (rather than the /16). That route will be the more specific route for the `169.254.1.0` net, and in particular for the `169.254.1.1` IP the OP comments he CAN use. This is true whether or not the OS supports the /16 natively. I don't know if setting the subnet is what you meant by "find a way to disable or override the automatic behavior" but setting a subnet will already be part of what OP is doing if they are configuring static IPs.

Comment: I think that in order for this to work using zeroconf and to avoid having to set `169.254` static IPs on the other hosts that want to access the web server on that net (an approach I would favor), you'd also need to add a route on the web server to tell it how to talk to the `192.168.180` net or it won't know how to route return packets and you'll get one sided communication.

Comment: @ssnobody I don't think you've read section 2.6.2 of RFC 3927. It makes the 169.254/16 subnet immune to subnet mismatch problems. Machines with IPv4 link-local addresses (and no routable addresses) are supposed to treat all subnets as local (so his web server won't need a route to 192.168.180/24). See the paragraph that's split between the bottom of page 14 and the top of page 15. I know that Apple's IP stacks have worked this way since at least 2001, maybe earlier. Mac OS 9, OS X, and iOS devices all do this. Even AirPort base stations and Xserve RAIDs do this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! You are correct; section 2.6.2 (which I had not read, along with most of the rest of that RFC) essentially says "ARP for everything" and a route would not have to be added for everything to just work if all devices support zeroconf. This still wouldn't prevent you from subnetting to /24 (i.e. where static IPs are configured). Whether `169.254.1.0` was or was not the network address for the network depended on  _which_ network we were talking about. I agree it is not the network address for the /16, but it certainly is for the /24.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that comes to my mind is adding a static route in your router.

For example, you might define that IP `169.254.1.0` with netmask `/32` (255.255.255.255) inside your `LAN` interface should use gateway `192.168.180.100` (assuming that's the server where the web server is).

[As Spiff states](https://superuser.com/questions/963401/want-to-setup-web-server-with-ip-that-is-not-on-my-local-network/963416#comment1317690_963416), that could not work if your router honors the section 2.6.2 of the RFC, as this would be CIDR address that should not be forwarded. However, I just tested this at home using a TP-Link TD-W8970 router and it indeed works, the packets are forwarded with the destination IP (169.254.1.0) untouched in the header.

Comment: This would require the OP to setup a router capable of forwarding traffic between those nets.

Comment: RFC 3927, which defines automatic IPv4 link-local addressing on the special 169.254/16 subnet, specifically forbids routers to forward packets to/from that subnet. See section 2.6.2.

Comment: @Spiff I'm not saying the contrary, I'm just trying to find a way the OP can simulate the behavior he needs. I just tried this by myself and it worked, so that's strange. Maybe because I didn't define the static route as /16 but /32 instead... however, as I said, packets are being forwarded to the defined gateway with the destination IP untouched in the header.

Comment: You said you saw no reason why it shouldn't work, and I was just giving you one. It shouldn't work if the router honors this well-established standards-track RFC. If his hosts follow the RFC, he shouldn't need it (also covered in section 2.6.2).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. You *can* actually use an out-of-subnet gateway; while quite unusual, I've seen a few networks do this.

- Note that the standard "netmask" and "gateway" settings merely expand to automatically-generated routes, more of which can be also set manually. (For example, a link route can be added to manually tell the OS that a device with a weird IP address is on the same LAN as you.)
- Also note that a network card can have *multiple* addresses assigned to it, and they can be from different subnets if needed. (Even Windows lets you do this, though unfortunately it requires DHCP to be disabled.)

---

Now, normally, you'd have several similar options, depending on who needs to reach your server. You could configure your router, or you could configure the client PCs themselves (but only if they're on the *same* router as the server).

Unfortunately, the specific `169.254.0.0/16` address range is designated as *non-routable*. Routers were written to *refuse* to forward packets with such IPs, no matter what configuration you have.

That limits the options somewhat. That is, the web server *must* be connected to the same LAN as you (that is, behind the same router).

---

So the one option remaining is: Add an `169.254.x.x/16` address on your own PC, *in addition to* the usual `192.168.180.x/24` one that you have.

In this case, configuring a gateway on the webserver is actually not required, since same-subnet communications don't use it anyway. (Though, of course, that means the webserver itself cannot connect very far.)

Comment: If you add a `169.254.x.x` address that is NOT on the `169.254.1.x` network, be sure you set the netmask on BOTH systems to `255.255.0.0`. If both systems will be on the `169.254.1.x` you may use the `255.255.255.0` netmask, though the either netmask will work in this case.